# Customize Highchart tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

I want to customize my tooltip. I want position certain series at a certain places. Like 2 series on top and 2 series on bottom.  I want this to look like this

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw3cT.png)

[Modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0js75.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-placement/

Also, how do I add arrow in the tooltip as well? Right now it comes only as a box.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Seattle HQ',
            'San Francisco',
            'Tokyo'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Employees'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Profit (millions)'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    legend: {
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
        data: [150, 73, 20],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    }, {
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
        data: [140, 90, 40],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    }, {
        name: 'Profit',
        color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
        data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Profit Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
        data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something like that you will need to use the `tooltip.formatter` [Api doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) and some CSS.

**JS**

```
tooltip: {      
    shared: true,
    useHTML:true,
    formatter: function(){
            var text = this.x + '<br>';
        text+= '<span class="number"><span style="color:' + this.points[0].color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.points[0].series.name + '</span><span class="number">' + '<span style="color:' + this.points[1].color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.points[1].series.name + '</span><br>';

        text+= '<span class="number">' + this.points[0].y+ '</span><span class="number">' +this.points[1].y+ '</span></br>'

        text+= '<span class="number"><span style="color:' + this.points[2].color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.points[2].series.name + '</span><span class="number">' + '<span style="color:' + this.points[3].color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.points[3].series.name + '</span><br>';

        text+= '<span class="number">' + this.points[2].y+ '</span><span class="number">' +this.points[3].y+ '</span></br>'
        return text;
    }
},
```

**CSS**

```
.number{
  width:34%;
  padding:1%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxytbkd4/)

Comment: Small Issue. I have a few series hidden by default. So the tooltip does not work at all. Anyway we can make it dynamic. Here is the same examples with couple of series hidden and tooltip is not working.              https://jsfiddle.net/jxytbkd4/